# minor edits get confusing feedback

Tags: bug, edits, error-message

I just edited two characters in a python-related answer, as the double-quotes in the answer were misleading. This two-character edit got two page messages on submission:

at the top of the page, above the form

```
Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.
```

and at the bottom of the form

```
Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?
```

This is confusing. Was my edit:

1. submitted and now subject to peer-review, or
2. not submitted?

Comment: One thing is for sure - it was not submitted, as your [suggestions tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/823020/nimasmi?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) is currently empty. The bug is in the feedback.

Comment: Anyway - like the first message says try making the edit more substantial e.g. fix some grammar, change "i" to "I" etc - 99% you can find four letters to fix so the edit is substantial enough to pass. If you really can't find what else to fix, post link here and 2K+ user can edit without those limitations.

Comment: That seems less 'authentic' than just subtly removing the offending characters and going on my merry way, satisfied with my guerrilla improvement of the world.

Comment: Feel free to correct yourselves: http://serverfault.com/questions/358580/django-dynamic-file-name (unless of course I'm mistaken that the `"` characters will be translated into `-` in the filename).

Comment: Are you sure your edit is even valid? Also why bother, on a question from February that has been closed as off-topic?

Comment: It checks out in my django installation. I've posted a [related question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835793/why-are-python-double-quotes-converted-to-hyphen-in-filename) as a result. As for why bother: to make the world a better place. The question in question is the top google hit for 'django export response dynamic filename', and a high-ranking and useful-looking hit for other similar searches. It would be nice if the answer there were correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edit was not submitted. The top message is always present, and the bottom message appeared only after you attempted to submit the edit.

This does seem potentially confusion, though. I propose we prefix the top message with "Upon submission," which would make it look like this:

[image]